# Laravel extract a section on json object

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, laravel

I am having a hard time to find a way to query a json object on my DB. I'll try to explain what I need. I have an object that will change mostly every day so this why I decided to store as json

```
"crew": [
            {
                "Crew": "CA001",
                "count": "1",
                "Craft": "CA",
                "craftType": "Carpenters",
                "members": [
                    {
                        "Badge": "10484658",
                        "Name": "Cudmore Gregory",
                        "Class": "Carpenter GF",
                        "shift": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Badge": "10484913",
                        "Name": "Harris Thomas",
                        "Class": "Carpenter JM",
                        "shift": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Badge": "10484658",
                        "Name": "Cudmore Gary",
                        "Class": "Carpenter GF",
                        "shift": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Badge": "10484913",
                        "Name": "Harris Joe",
                        "Class": "Carpenter JM",
                        "shift": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }...

        ]
```

What I need to do is able to query example where Crew = 'CA001' or  members where shift = 2 and Only return an array with the match values.

So far I have found this about to query, but it's returning the all object!

```
        $crew = CtcCrew::where('userID', $user->userID)->where('companyID', $user->companyID)
        //->whereJsonContains('dataCrew', ['crew' => ['Crew' => 'CA001']])->first();
        ->whereJsonContains('dataCrew', ['crew' => ['members' => ['Badge' => '10484658']]])->first();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Please test the given code and keep me posted in the comments below.

```
// fetch crew data
$crews = CtcCrew::where('userID', $user->userID)
    ->where('companyID', $user->companyID)
    ->first();


// convert the crew information from json to an array
$crewData = json_decode($crews->dataCrew, true);


$return = collect($crewData)->map(function ($crew) {
    $memberFound = false;
    $memberFound = collect($crew['members'])->map(function ($member) {
        if ($member['shift'] == 2) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    if ($crew['Crew'] == 'CA001' || $memberFound) {
        return $crew;
    }
})->filter();  // filter to remove null values
```

Comment: I ended doing something like this :

$data = collect($CtcCrew->data['crew']);
$crew =  $data->where('crew', $crewID)->first();

thanks for the hint